# Complex Find and Replace in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have a list of ProductName key/value pairs, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductNames]
(
    [Key] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](100) NULL
)
```

Containing values like this:

```
'Pepsi', 'Pepsi®'
'Coke', 'Coke®'
```

I need to find and replace values in a text field that DO NOT ALREADY contain the registered trademark for a product...and replace it with the full trademark string.

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
 1. if 'Pepsi' is alone....it becomes 'Pepsi®'
 2. if 'Pepsi®' already exists...do nothing
```

**UPDATE:**
The registered trademark is only one example of something to be replaced.  There could be other multi-character replacements as well.  As such, something more complex is probably needed.  For example, I would probably detect 'Pepsi', then truncate 'Pepsi' from the VALUE portion of the key/value row...AND THEN...try to detect if that truncated value already exists in the string.  If not, then go ahead and replace the value (something like that).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this solution will help you. It will update records where `value` does not end with `®`, appending it at the end.

```
update ProductNames
set Value = Value + '®'
where Value not like '%®'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  However, the registered trademark is only a single example of what is in the source table.

Answer (score 0):

```
update ProductNames set 
   Value = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('®',value,1) = 0 then value+'®' else value end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an easy way for this to work.  Iterate through each special keyword and check the beginning, middle and end cases for these words, assuming you require white space to separate each keyword.  Break down the operation into a few steps, as required by business logic.  Expensive yes, but it's a one time thing, I assume.  Better yet, run this routine once when a row is added/modified.